# i have a rotating image in android.When stop button is clicked the image needs to stopped at the exact position

Tags: android

i have an image in my application...
when i click the start button the image needs to rotate..
when i click the stop button the image is set to original position...
instead i want the image to be stopped at the exact position..
here's my code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ImageView my_image;
    AnimationListener listener;
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listener = new AnimationListener() {
        @Override public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}
        @Override public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            System.out.println("End Animation!");
            //load_animations();
        }
    };

    my_image=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    load_animations();
    Button start=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button stop=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);


}
void load_animations()
{
    Button start=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button stop=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);

    new AnimationUtils();
    final Animation rotation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.animation);
    rotation.setAnimationListener(listener);
    start.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             my_image.startAnimation(rotation);
        }
    });
    stop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        my_image.clearAnimation();  

        }
    });

}

}
```

Comment: Okay.  Is there something wrong with the code?

Comment: Try adding `rotation.setFillAfter(true);` in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you need to stop the image at the exact position. Use the ObjectAnimator instead...This supports from API 11

```
ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(my_image,"rotationY", 360f);
animator.setDuration(1000);
animator.setRepeatCount(ObjectAnimator.INFINITE);
```

In the start button click..

```
animator.start();
```

In the stop button click..

```
animator.cancel();
```

Comment: its working fine... but wen when i click start again its rotating from the initial position and not from the position where it stopped..

Answer (score 0):

Use below code inside load_animations() method:

```
final Animation rotation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.animation);
rotation.setDuration(10000000);
rotation.setAnimationListener(listener);
```